# Is training a model (using clf.fit()) with the same dataset making it any better?

Tags: python, machine-learning

This might be a stupid question, but here goes anyway.

I'm doing a machine learning algorithm for sentiment analysis. So I have a dataset that I split using k-fold cross validation. Then I get new vectors for words, chars, etc. Using hstack and chi2 I get chi2_Train.

Afterwards I set clf=randomforest() and I do clf.fit(chi2_Train,target_data). I then upload these models.

Since I create a new clf.fit() everytime (given that I can't reuse existing model since fit would delete previous paramaters), is it making my model any better? I don't see how it is...

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you asking about saving the model and reusing it later?

Comment: My question is everytime I use clf.fit(), it overwrites the clf and then I save the model. Is this making the model better with everytime I run clf.fit() if the data is the same?